# Are there any official solutions for baby rudin?

Tags: real-analysis

I could only find solutions written by other people, and their answers vary. I have some difficulty understanding the solutions for exercise 1.6 c and d. Why does it make sense to define that for every real x?[image: Question]

Comment: You seem to be asking two very different questions in one.